# Excel ComboBox not allowing me to type decimals

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a combobox on an Excel spreadsheet that has a ListFillRange of numbers(Double). The list fills fine. However, when I try to type a value such as 1000.0001, I cannot type the decimal point. I can, however,  select it from the dropdown list.

Also, as it may be connected to the problem, it seems the list is filled with strings although the ListFillRange is formatted as doubles. Are ComboBoxes always filled as strings?

Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: it seams. You can use =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(E3;".";",")) with E3 LinkedCell...

Comment: What do you have in the validation settings for the dropdown?  Is it set to only allow certain input?  Also, is this created programmatically(vba?) and can you post the code?

Comment: It's set to MatchRequired = True. The ComboBox is not created programmatically, but the ListFillrange is filled with one line of code.   .cmbAccount.ListFillRange = "COA"